# socket hang up error with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, proxy

I want to set up proxy for some XYZ server whose i am not the admin.
Then i want to do some analysis over the request and response headers then also over request and response bodies.
So i am using http-proxy https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

this is what i am doing :

```
  var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();


  connect.createServer(
    connect.bodyParser(),
    require('connect-restreamer')(),
    function (req, res) {
      proxy.web(req, res, { target : 'XYZserver' });
    }
  ).listen(config.listenPort);
```

Upto GET request everything is fine but whenever a request with some body like POST, PATCH, PUT etc request are made i get the error :

```
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1472:15)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1522:23)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at TCP.close (net.js:466:12)
```

I google a lot but found no clue whats wrong going on.
I enable socket proxy with 'ws:true' option of 'proxy.web' but still the same error.

Answer (score 28):

Just for sake of completeness, there is really an integration problem between modules `body-parser` and `http-proxy`, as stated in [this](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/40) thread.

If you can't change the order of the middleware; You can **restream** the parsed body before proxying the request.

```
// restream parsed body before proxying
proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
    if (req.body) {
        let bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        // incase if content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded -> we need to change to application/json
        proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(bodyData));
        // stream the content
        proxyReq.write(bodyData);
    }
}
```

I've lost 2 days on this f***** problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: You are a hero.

Comment: You can also change the order of middlewares to make it work

Comment: @ospider, the answer starts with a precondition: "_If you can't change the order of the middleware_" :)

Answer (score 27):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by moving my proxy code above other node middleware.

e.g. This:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
app.use("/someroute", function(req, res) {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://someurl.com'})
});

app.use(someMiddleware);
```

not this:

```
app.use(someMiddleware);

var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
app.use("/someroute", function(req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://someurl.com'})
});
```

My specific issue was having BodyParser middleware above the proxy. I haven't done much digging but it must have modified the request in some way that broke the proxy library when the request finally came to it.

Comment: Ok, but if you put body-parser after the proxy usage you cannot modify the body of the request :(

Comment: @Michael - will below code work fine ?

`import BodyParser from 'body-parser';
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();


app.use("/someroute", function(req, res) {
  if (some conditions) {
   req.url = '/abc';
    app.handle(req, res);
 } else {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://someurl.com'})
 }
});

app.use(someMiddleware);
app.use(compression());
const jsonParser = BodyParser.json();

app.post('/abc', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
 // some code
 res.send(some data);
});`

Answer (score 7):

Need catching proxy's errors:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({ target: argv.proxy_url })

proxy.on('error', function(err, req, res) {
    res.end();
})
```

Answer (score 5):

After wasting more than a day and following some posts in [nodejitsu/node-http-proxy issues](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues) I was able to make it working thanks to riccardo.cardin.
I've decided to post full example to save you time. 
The below example uses server [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express), [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) (req.body middleware) and ofcourse [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/) to proxy and forward request to 3rd party server.

```
const webapitargetUrl = 'https://posttestserver.com/post.php'; 

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies

var https = require('https');
  var stamproxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
      target: 'https://localhost:8888',
      changeOrigin: true,
      agent  : https.globalAgent, 
      toProxy : true,
      secure: false,
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      } 
    });

  stamproxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
      console.log("proxying for",req.url);
      if (req.body) {
        console.log("prxyReq req.body: ",req.body);
        // modify the request. Here i just by removed ip field from the request you can alter body as you want
        delete req.body.ip;
        let bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        // in case if content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded -> we need to change to application/json
        proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(bodyData));
        // stream the content
        console.log("prxyReq bodyData: ",bodyData);
        proxyReq.write(bodyData);
      }
      console.log('proxy request forwarded succesfully');
  });

  stamproxy.on('proxyRes', function(proxyRes, req, res){    
    proxyRes.on('data' , function(dataBuffer){
        var data = dataBuffer.toString('utf8');
        console.log("This is the data from target server : "+ data);
    }); 
  });


app.use(compression());
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'static', 'favicon.ico')));

app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'static')));


var sessions = require("client-sessions");
app.use(sessions({
  secret: 'blargadeeblargblarg',
  cookieName: 'mysession'
}));

app.use('/server/setserverip', (req, res) => {

    console.log('------------ Server.js /server/setserverip  ---------------------------------');
    req.mysession.serverip += 1;

    console.log('session data:');
    console.log(req.mysession.serverip)
    console.log('req.body:');
    console.log(req.body);

    // Proxy forwarding   
    stamproxy.web(req, res, {target: webapitargetUrl});
    console.log('After calling proxy serverip');

});
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `http-proxy` is not compatible with `body-parser` middleware.
You may want to move the `http-proxy` middleware before `body-parser` or stop using `body-parser`.

See also:
[Socket hangup while posting request to Node-http-proxy Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632854/socket-hangup-while-posting-request-to-node-http-proxy-node-js)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with ***post***, ***put*** and ***delete***, but after read [this issue](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/40) from **chimurai
/
http-proxy-middleware**, I have done it.
**1-** Add **onProxyReq**: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/40#issuecomment-249430255
**2-** Notice that you have to add **Content-Type: application/json** to request's header
**3-** No change order of body-parser

Comment: for me, `restream parsed body before proxying function` fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`http-proxy-middleware` is similar package that uses `http-proxy` and it was created specifically for:

> Configure proxy middleware with ease for connect, express, browser-sync and many more.

This package inherits the same issue of the body-parser, however, the fix (`fixRequestBody`) is included in the package. here is an example from the docs.

```
const { createProxyMiddleware, fixRequestBody } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const proxy = createProxyMiddleware({
  /**
    * Fix bodyParser
  **/
 onProxyReq: fixRequestBody,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Post` requests this error could be caused by the `stream` consumed by the `bodyParser`. You need to re-create the stream and pass it to the proxy.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  // verify function has access to buff that contains the stream
  // create a new readable stream and save it to streamBody
  verify: (req, res, buf, encoding) => {
  const readableStream = Readable.from(buf);
  req.streamBody = readableStream
 }
}));
 // Your stream was already consumed by bodyParser you must pass it 
 // again to the param "buffer"
proxy.web(req, res, {
 target: "target-here",
 buffer: req.streamBody
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me
eg

```
app.use(
  "/flightService",
  ValidateUserMiddleware.authentication,
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: FLIGHT_SERVICE_ADDRESS,
    changeOrigin: true,
    onProxyReq: fixRequestBody,
    pathRewrite: { ["^/flightService"]: "" },
  })
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).