# socket hangup with nodejs proxy to communicate front end to backend service

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, http-proxy

I have 2 containers - `frontend_service` is a nodejs frontend application built using react. I have a `backend_service` which has my business logic and communicates to `MongoDB`. The frontend communications to the backend via a proxy. I try to communicate to the backend service via the self-discovered service name in my cluster.

For example, I have code that calls the user api `axios.get(`/api/v1/users${window.location.search}`).then`

the frontend express server proxies that request to the backend service like so

```
// using http-proxy
      app.all('/api/v1', (req, res) => {
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://backend_service', changeOrigin: true });
      });
```

I have setup my backend and frontend services in kubernetes, however, when the `api/v1` is called from my app the request does not go through and times out like it cannot resolve the DNS. I get a `socket hang up` error

The weird thing is that if I enter the running frontend docker container and `curl http://backend_service` it works as expected.

I'm super confused why the request does not go through when executed via the `http-proxy` in my express server

Comment: Order of middleware may matter according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632854/socket-hangup-while-posting-request-to-node-http-proxy-node-js?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?